# Asp.Net Webforms Session Key null on first page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have the following situation:

On a page I call a HttpHandler. In this handler I'm setting a Session variable.
Then I go to another page and want to read the value stores in the session (Key is transfered via querystring).

Now, on every "first load" (e.g. app-pool recycle) die session is present but has no values. 
After that all works like expected...

The HttpHandler is defenitly hit (checked via breakpoint).

Has somebody an idea what problem there might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I called the HttpHandler from Javascript ASYNC!
So there was a timing problem the first time the site got called. I moved the second page call to wait for the HttpHandler to complete.

That should have done the trick.